# Vision transformer is throwing error during training

Tags: transformer-model

I AM TRYING TO create a sequence to sequence model for license plate text recognition. I have a  data file lpr.csv with license plate image and label. I have 4000 license plate images that i am # #feeding to the model. While training I am getting the following error.

Node: 'gradient_tape/model_53/tf.**operators**.add_531/BroadcastGradientArgs'
Incompatible shapes: [20,0,64] vs. [20,0,32]
[[{{node gradient_tape/model_53/tf.**operators**.add_531/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]
[Op:__inference_train_function_758198]

`

```
 import tensorflow as tf
   from tensorflow.keras import layers

   # Define Vision Transformer block

   class VisionTransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, mlp_dim, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(VisionTransformerBlock, self).__init__()
        self.attention = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
        self.mlp = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(mlp_dim, activation=tf.nn.gelu), layers.Dropout(dropout_rate),  
            layers.Dense(embed_dim)]       
        )
        self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        attn_output = self.attention(inputs, inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        mlp_output = self.mlp(out1)
        mlp_output = self.dropout2(mlp_output, training=training)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + mlp_output)

   class PatchEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, patch_size, embed_dim):
        super(PatchEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.patch_size = patch_size
        self.projection = layers.Conv2D(embed_dim, kernel_size=patch_size, strides=patch_size,  
          padding="valid")
    def call(self, inputs):
        patches = self.projection(inputs)
        return tf.reshape(patches, [tf.shape(patches)[0], -1, tf.shape(patches)[-1]])

    def get_positional_embedding(patch_embeddings, embed_dim):
         num_patches = tf.shape(patch_embeddings)[1]
         positions = tf.range(num_patches, dtype=tf.float32)
         angle_rads = positions[:, tf.newaxis] / tf.pow(10000, tf.range(0, embed_dim, 2,   
         dtype=tf.float32) / embed_dim)   
    sin_vals = tf.math.sin(angle_rads[:, 0::2])
    cos_vals = tf.math.cos(angle_rads[:, 1::2])
    pos_encoding = tf.stack([sin_vals, cos_vals], axis=-1)
    pos_encoding = tf.reshape(pos_encoding, [num_patches, -1])
    pos_encoding = tf.expand_dims(pos_encoding, 0)
    return tf.tile(pos_encoding, [tf.shape(patch_embeddings)[0], 1, 1])

    def VisionTransformer(image_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=image_shape)

    patch_size = 16  # Define your patch size
    embed_dim = 64  # Embedding dimension for each patch
    num_heads = 8
    mlp_dim = 256
    num_layers = 8

    # Patch embeddings
    patch_embeddings = PatchEmbedding(patch_size, embed_dim)(inputs)

    # Positional embeddings
    positional_embeddings = get_positional_embedding(patch_embeddings, embed_dim)
    embeddings = patch_embeddings + positional_embeddings

    # Transformer Encoder Blocks

for _ in range(num_layers):
        attn_output = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)(embeddings, 
        embeddings)
        attn_output = layers.Dropout(0.1)(attn_output)
        attn_output = layers.Add()([embeddings, attn_output])  # Adjusted operation
        attn_output = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(attn_output)

        mlp_output = layers.Dense(mlp_dim, activation='relu')(attn_output)
        mlp_output = layers.Dropout(0.1)(mlp_output)
        mlp_output = layers.Dense(embed_dim)(mlp_output)
        mlp_output = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(mlp_output)

        embeddings = layers.Add()([mlp_output, attn_output])  # Adjusted operation


    # Global average pooling and classify

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(embeddings)
    x = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

   # Create the Vision Transformer model and compile it

    image_shape = (224, 224, 3)
    num_classes = len(train_generator.class_indices)
    vision_transformer = VisionTransformer(image_shape, num_classes)
    vision_transformer.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=  
    ['accuracy'])
   # Print model summary
    vision_transformer.summary()

   # Train the model
    vision_transformer.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=val_generator)
```